# cardano_node_metrics_connectedPeers_int empty since node upgrade 1.35.7 -> 8.1.2

Tags: cardano-node

Since i upgraded my nodes from 1.35.7 to 8.1.2 the `cardano_node_metrics_connectedPeers_int` variable is empty.

All others are set as expected.

I already loaded the newest config, because `ConwayGenesisFile` was missing and set `TraceBlockFetchDecisions` again to true.

Are there any changes regarding cardano_node_metrics_connectedPeers_int in the new versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is been changed from `cardano_node_metrics_connectedPeers_int` to `cardano_node_metrics_peers_connectedPeers_int`

If I recall correctly changes was brought since 8.0.0 version.